# Fonts and Template File for Journal "Mathematical Notes" by Springer

Tags: fonts, templates

Dear Friends: Like most of you, I care for the aesthetics of the font and presentation of my work in Tex.

I am interested in the Tex template file for Journal called **"Mathematical Notes"** which is published by **Springer**. Unfortunately, I am unable to find a template that matches their publication.

If you some one can find me the template or even identify the fonts used in the layout, it would make me happy! The fonts look like a variant of the family: **Obyknovennaya Novaya**

I am attaching a screen shot.

[image: Sample Layout of an article from Mathematcal Notes]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5764)

Comment: The font seems to be `LiteraturnayaISOC`, as can be identified from sample articles found here : http://www.springer.com/mathematics/journal/11006?hideChart=1#realtime

Comment: _Thanks!_ Any guesses on the template?

Comment: Try this: http://www.mathnet.ru/supplement/authornotes/mzsty.zip, a russian site, with the relevant content of the russian version of the mathematical notes (untested!)